# Redux updating state too slow after axios.post call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So i'm trying to apply a simple login functionality using react, redux.
By using axios post request sending to a django server (username, password)
But the problem is from the component its been called from.
For example component A.
So scenario is like this:

1. user enter username and password and clicking a submit
2. handle submit fires action method called onAuth(authLogin)
3. authLogin updating the state if successded or not

- *the problem is that the state is being updated to slow and state.error has no value
  which makes me redirecting the user somewhere when he didn't enter valid username,pass*
  **How can wait for the axios call to finish and wait for state update?**

  ```
  class A extends Component{
    handleSubmit = (values) => {
        this.props.onAuth(values.username, values.password);
        if(!this.props.error){
           // redirecting somewherr
        }else{
           // giving error message
        }
    }

   render() {
    return{
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <Input name="username"/>
        <Input name="password"/>
       </Form>
    }

  }
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return {
       error: state.error,
     };
  };

     const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
             onAuth: (username, password) => 
    dispatch(actions.authLogin(username,password)),
      };
  };
  ```

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginView);

}

- **My initial state**

  const initialState = {
  token: null,
  error: null,
  loading: false,
  };
- **Login action**

  ```
    export const authLogin = (username, password) => {
      return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(authStart());
      axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        // some more code here
        dispatch(authSuccess(token));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(authFail(err));
      });
  };
  ```

  };
- **authFail action**

  ```
  export const authFail = (error) => {
   return {
     type: actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL,
     error: error,
  ```

  } ;
  };

Answer (score 0):

Think the to handle with this issue is using setTimeout function of the redirect function

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // redirecting function call
   }, 3000);
```

That fixed it for me